# Object viewer control needed (like QuickWatch in VS)

Tags: c#, wpf

Anyone know of any controls that you can add to your application to allow the user to check out the content of an object? I'm thinking of something like QuickWatch in Visual Studio, just list all properties of an object and its values and allow the user to drill down. I started writing one using reflection but it turned out be a lot of work to handle different kind of collections. This functionality would be used for debugging purposes mostly and not by regular users.

I prefer WPF but Winforms would work as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try [this](http://www.sliver.com/dotnet/statebrowser/)

Comment: I accepted your answer even though I will not use it. The link is only to a dll, no sourcecode. Also it uses winforms and not WPF. It throws exception which will close down the window.

Answer (score 1):

[Snoop](http://blois.us/Snoop/) is amazing. Also check out [Crack.NET](http://www.codeplex.com/cracknetproject).

Comment: I am looking for a control which can be integrated within an application and not a standalone application like Snoop.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you are looking for http://comparenetobjects.codeplex.com/

You can use and modify to suit your purpose and also add a UI yourself